# Angular material 15 mat-tab-nav-bar router-outlet

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm stuck in my code following the migration of angular material components (https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview#tabs-and-navigation). To improve accessibility, I need to put the router-outlet in the mat-tab-nav-panel.
I currently have code like this

```
<div class="app-content">
 <div class="app-header">
  <app-header [title]="title"></app-header>
  <app-tabs [tabs]="tabs"></intent-tabs>
 </div>

 <section class="app-main">
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
 </section>
</div>
```

With in app-tab my definition of tabs (mat-tab-link) but I should have my <mat-tab-nav-panel #tabPanel> in my 'section' and not in my component app-tab but I can't figure out how to do it

```
<section class="app-main">
  <mat-tab-nav-panel #tabPanel><router-outlet></router-outlet></mat-tab-nav-panel>
</section>
```

I've tried passing the reference via input in app-tab but without success. Do you have any ideas on how to get around my problem?